# Extract values from a list using indices in another list

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I have a list of indices:

```
indices = [1, 8, 18, 28, 37, 47, 57, 66, 67, 72]
```

I have another list of values:

```
values = [,1,2,3,4,5,.....,3,2,4,5,3,1,3,4]
```

I need to get the values that are in the indices list. So the value at index 1, 8, 18, etc.

I thought something like indices[values] would work.

I'm working with Pandas.

Comment: Try `values[indices]` [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Comment: The simplest way is using `operator.itemgetter`, `operator.itemgetter(*indices)(values)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Convert to numpy array first

```
a = np.array(values)
x = (list(a[indices]))

print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using zip function & dict constructor, You can made Series Object.
Indices is like keys

```
pd.Series(dict(zip(indices, values)))
```